# How to escape from escape sequence in a string variable

Tags: java, c#, string, escaping

I tried to initialize string variable to path of one of the file. It reports that the escape sequence is not valid. Any Solution?

```
String s="F:\abc\xyz.txt";
```

Comment: Any specific language?

Comment: The "\" character has a special meaning, for "escaping" or changing the meaning of the next character ("\t" means a tab character for example). Because it has the job of creating escape sequences, if you actually want a \ character in your string you need to use the escape sequence "\\", which will be translated to the \ character.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. That work like a charm  :)

Comment: C#. The other method, if you put a @ symbol before the string, it treats the string as literal, and ignores the escape characters. I.E. String s = @"F:\abc\xyz.txt";

Answer (score 0):

Converting @Hank D and @Seige's comments to an answer:

In Java and C# (it's hard to tell which language you're using here, but it's likely one of those two), the backslash character `\` is used to start *escape sequences* you can use to include special characters in your string that you can't normally type on the keyboard or that would otherwise cause problems. For example, you can put a newline in a string by writing `\n`:

```
String multiline = "This String\nSpans Multiple\nLines!";
```

You can include Unicode characters with the `\U` sequence:

```
String heart = "I \U2764 Escape Sequences!";
```

And you can include nested quotes with the `\"` sequence:

```
String quotation = "Quoth the raven, \"Nevermore.\"";
```

In your case, you're trying to use the `\` character as a path separator, but Java/C# is interpreting what you're doing as trying to build invalid escape sequences. That is, the string

```
F:\abc\xyz.txt
```

is getting interpreted as

```
F:(\a)bc(\x)yz.txt
```

To fix this, you can use the fact that the escape sequence `\\` stands for a backslash and write the string like this:

```
String s = "F:\\abc\\xyz.txt";
```

Fun fact: The reason that the backslash was chosen as the path separator in Java/C# is that it was chosen that way in C because that character was so rarely used... and then DOS/Windows came along and broke everything. :-)

Alternatively, in C#, you can write

```
String s = @"F:\abc\xyz.txt";
```

The @ prefix disables escape sequences in the string, which makes things a lot easier to read.